# LINQ NOT Field LIKE String - String LIKE Field

Tags: linq

i want do to this:

```
SELECT table.field FROM table WHERE ((("030232334156") Like [field] & "*"));
```

(It's from Access, it works :))

with LINQ.
How can I do this?

It's **NOT** Field LIKE String, it's String LIKE Field.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Could you just add an example of what you wanna achieve ? Some data and expected result ?

Comment: Its as TAPI-Blocker with wildcard-entries. In table is stored telephone-number like 0302323. Now when TAPI detects caller-id like 0302323-1 or 0302323-2 or 0302323-3 linq should match 0302323. So you dont have to insert n numbers for all the direct-callings of a company in table because TAPI blocks the main-number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
yourData.Where(m => "0302323-1".StartsWith(m.yourField));
```

Comment: Great! And so easy when you know it. :) Thank you!

Comment: If it's fine, you can accept this answer to "close" the question.